# How do I call __import__ when dynamically importing in python

Tags: python

I am just playing around with the dynamically importing a module example as they do in 16.15 of dive into python.

I am doing something like

```
modulenames = ['my_module']
modules = list(map(__import__, modulenames))
modules[0].process()
```

However my model is in a subdirectory (called 'modules') so instead of

```
import my_module
```

I would do

```
from modules import my_module
```

The import dunder accepts a fromlist where I (presumably?) can pass the subdirectory but I cant quite figure out the syntax to add it inside the map() call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way:

```
from importlib import import_module

module_list = ('package.a', 'package.b')
modules = [import_module(module) for module in module_list]
modules[0].process()
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#import__), you can just do :

```
modules = __import__("modules", fromlist=["my_module"])
```

and then acces it with `modules.my_module`

Comment: Thanks, that works. I found in the docs somewhere a note saying using importlib is preferred to using __import__ so I'll accept the answer below that does this.